# Fullscreen Video

Tags: jquery, html

I work in video player, and I am having trouble with fullscreen systems. How can I toggle video into full screen mode?

My current script is as follows:

```
<script>
$("#nome").click( function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("nome");       
    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
         element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
         element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside a DOCUMENT ready event.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#nome").click( function() {
    if ($(this).mozRequestFullScreen) {
         $(this).mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if ($(this).webkitRequestFullScreen) {
         $(this).webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }  
  });
});
</script>
```

Also, you can reference to the current element using `$(this)` in jQuery. You don't need to refer a new element select by using `document.getElementById()`.

Here is a tutorial for you on the JavaScript API to detect the FullScreen support on (almost) all of the browsers. Including Desktop and Mobile browsers.

http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Good luck!